# Primefaces, p:datatable - how to make constant height while paginating?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

While `<p:datatable>` in a **scroll mode** it's simple, just make `scrollHeight="150"` attribute and everything is fine. But how to make constant height while paginating? I tried to use css but it stretches the rows to gap the height and it's ugly. Is there another solution?

Comment: I always see a constant height of `<p:dataTable>` with equal page size when it is paginated.

Comment: @Tiny, yes but when there're enough rows to fill the datatable, when there aren't enough rows it shrinks.

Comment: It will then look rather ugly, If we have 50 rows per page and if the last page or the only page (in case the data table has only a single page) has one or two rows, for example. The only single row will be stretched vertically to fit the entire data table :) (We should not be interested in explicitly setting the minimum height of the data table in that case. Are you interested to be explicit?)

Comment: What do I want that bottom line of the table will be at constant distance from the upper line, i.e. it creates space of certain size to fit for example 10 rows. When I add row it will fit this space until it will fit all the space and then move to another page.